# Django admin: adding objects for foreignkey from other side

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

so I have these two models

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    short_description = HTMLField(max_length=400)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='recipe_likes')
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=datetime.now)
    ratings = GenericRelation(Rating, related_query_name='recipes')

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='recipe_ingredients')
```

In the admin panel from the recipes section, if I choose a recipe I want to be able to add ingredients for that recipe, what do I need? I think I don't know the right searchterms to use, hope you understand what I mean.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT
This is the solution:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Recipe, Ingredient

class IngredientInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Ingredient
    extra = 3

@admin.register(Recipe)
class RecipeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title',)
    search_fields = ('title', )
    inlines = [IngredientInline,]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Recipe, Ingredient

class IngredientInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Ingredient
    extra = 3

@admin.register(Recipe)
class RecipeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title',)
    search_fields = ('title', )
    inlines = [IngredientInline,]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to read up on `InlineModelAdmin`s:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

When you register your models with a model admin class, add an `inlines` list.

The documentation is good on this, so please expand your question if you have more detailed questions!